# How can I solve $(f\circ g) = h^{\circ 2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, soft-question

Functional equations of the form $$f\circ g = h^{\circ 2}$$
How can they be approached? In other words, given a function $h$ how to find functions $f,g$ so that :$$f(g(x)) = h(h(x))$$

Of course I am not very interested in the trivial solution $f=g=h$ but if we force $g\neq h, f\neq h$.

---

**EDIT** I am more interested in generic methods or algorithms to solve it than actual solutions.

Comment: Are you interested in other trivial solutions like $f(x) = h(x+1)$ and $g(x) = h(x)-1$?

Comment: $\alpha, \alpha_1 \in \mathbf{R}$, then : $f:x \rightarrow x^{\alpha}$, $g:x \rightarrow x^{\alpha ^2 / \alpha_1}$, $h:x \rightarrow x^{\alpha}$ is always solution so there are infinitely many solutions...

Comment: Obviously, if $p$ is an invertible function, then $g=p\circ h$ and $f=h\circ p^{-1}$ gives a solution. But these may not be the only cases...

Comment: @Bob1123: I am more looking for methods or algorithms to solve it than actual solutions. :)

Comment: With the amount of solutions you've been given, and the ease/speed they were given with, I doubt anybody has actually ever bothered describing methods/algorithms for solving it.

Comment: @Henrik: Okay, then maybe we are simply missing each others points I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the functions have inverses, then pick any $g(x)$ and define $f(x) = h(h(g^{-1}(x)))$.